# Why is Z < Z > Z (with Z integer array) an illegal expression in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

This comes from Nicolas Rougier's numpy exercises (https://github.com/rougier/numpy-100), #27.

Suppose `Z = np.array([1,2,3])`. 
The expression `Z < Z > Z` gives a `ValueError`.
However, observe that the following expressions evaluate just fine:

```
(Z < Z) > Z
Z < (Z > Z)
Z.__le__(Z).__gt__(Z)
```

Note also that for a scalar Z (e.g. `Z = 3`), `Z < Z > Z` parses (and obviously evaluates to `False`). What's going on?

Comment: Let me know with a mention if you're still confused.

Comment: The key difference is that `a<b` produces a boolean array.